# Restrict IP Address to access Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have publish my Web Application in IIS and I getting Error while running

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SecurityHttpModule'.

My Web Config Like

```
    <httpModules>  
    <add name="SecurityHttpModule type="SecurityHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
```

My SecurityHttpModule Like

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    public interface IHttpModule
    { }
    namespace BankSuite 
    {
    public class SecurityHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
    public SecurityHttpModule() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)source).Context;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (!IsValidIpAddress(ipAddress))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  // (Forbidden)

        }
    }

    private bool IsValidIpAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        return (ipAddress == "127.0.0.1");
    }

    public void Dispose() { /* clean up */ }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your XML is not valid with the 3 x " ?

Comment: Why did you define your own `IHttpModule`? Anyway the name attribute must also contain the assembly name.

Comment: Not Cleared to me,please share more details3

Comment: You can set IP restrictions [at the IIS level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831785.aspx). You can even [add the restrictions directly in your web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/). Blocking IPs at the IIS level is cheaper than allowing the call to reach the web site. Do you *really* need to hand-code the same feature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a closing quote on the `name`
make sure it is not like that in reall config

Try specify using `Fully qualified name` such as `NamespaceQualifiedTypeName, AssemblyName`

so something like `BankSuite.SecurityHttpModule, AssemblyName` - where `AssemblyName` correspond to your dll name

also if you are using iis 7+ with integrated mode, use

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="SecurityHttpModule" type="BankSuite.SecurityHttpModule, AssemblyName"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

instead.